# How to set HttpPost endpoint from jquery, in asp.net application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, http-post

I am trying to get an [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com/) jQuery example to work. Basically it is just a way to upload files from client page to the webserver.

There is an example on how to set up the file stream on the server side on the [project's GitHub page](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/tree/master/server/ASP.NET%20MVC%20C#).

How do I from script call this HttpPost `endpoint`? The simple jQuery example looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
        request: {
          endpoint: 'WhatToWriteHere??'
        },
        debug: true
      });
    });
```

So what do you type in the `endpoint`? I suppose it would be something like `Namespace.Namespace.ClassName.UploadMethod()`, but I've been fiddling along time with it, but cant get it to work. When debugging with Firebug, I get the following error(s):

```
405 Method Not Allowed  
[FineUploader] xhr - server response received for 0
The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/FineUploaderTest/Uploadfolder' is not allowed.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a [generic HttpHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332579/what-is-generic-handler-in-asp-net-and-its-use) to handle the file upload:

```
public class UploadHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var request = context.Request;
        var formUpload = request.Files.Count > 0;

        var xFileName = request.Headers["X-File-Name"];
        var qqFile = request["qqfile"];
        var formFilename = formUpload ? request.Files[0].FileName : null;

        var filename = xFileName ?? qqFile ?? formFilename;
        var inputStream = formUpload ? request.Files[0].InputStream : request.InputStream;

        var filePath = Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), filename);
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
        {
            inputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write("{\"success\":true}");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
        request: {
            endpoint: '/uploadhandler.ashx'
        },
        debug: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. 
Ive tried to add the generic handler you suggested, and changed the endpoint to the handlers file name, but it still doesent work.

When i debug with Firebug, I now get the error:
[FineUploader] Processing 1 files or inputs...
[FineUploader] Sending upload request for 0
[FineUploader] xhr - server response received for 0
HTTP Error 404 - Not Found.

So it seems it cannot find the handler..

Comment: Make sure that the name of the handler is correct. Also if you have a virtual directory name in the url make sure you have specified it. You could use the `ResolveUrl` method to set the path to the handler in a correct way: `endpoint: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/uploadhandler.ashx") %>'`.