# Binary Write using ASP.NET into a new tab / window

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, response, contenttype

I am using VB.NET to write a pdf file directly to the browser, which opens it right away replacing the content in a current window. I am trying to do is set a parameter which will cause binarywrite in a new tab / window.

```
' Set the appropriate ContentType.
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf"

' Write file directly to browser.
Response.BinaryWrite(binaryData)
Response.End()
```

There is has to be something that I can set which will cause this to write binary PDF in a new window. Like Response.Target = "_blank" ?????

Comment: "target" is defined client-side in the "a" tag.  It would be a serious security caveat if you could target a client window from a server-side command.

Comment: ""target" is defined client-side in the "a" tag. It would be a serious security caveat if you could target a client window from a server-side command." I don't see how that is because I have the option to stream to PDF file ( I can do that ), or the browser window ( I can do that ), I am sure there is an option for ContentType to set it to try to open in a new tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, create an additional page named "PDF.aspx" or whatever you would like it called.

Second, in your page, store your "binarydata" variable in a session.

```
Session("binaryData") = binarydata
```

And tell it to go to your new page.

```
Response.Redirect("PDF.aspx")
```

Third, go to your PDF.aspx code behind page and put the following:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles       Me.Load
    Try
         Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf"
         Response.BinaryWrite(Session("binaryData"))
         Response.End()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

That should produce the result you want. :)

Comment: I thought there would be an easier way to do this but I guess that is the only way. Thank you.

Comment: @MikeR. PDF.aspx should likely be a generic handler (PDF.ashx), as you don't need the overhead of an entire page.

Comment: @WyattTroutman No problem. Generic handlers are very useful for obtaining documents or images or other binary files from a database. You can even use them to serve static (regular files) and use them for authorization or download statistics etc. One of the most common uses I see of generic handlers is retrieving images from a database for display in a GridView, with the image id being passed via query string.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but here's what I had done to achieve the OP was after. *(Forgive me as this is C# but it shouldn't be too hard to convert it)*

This is the original code that I had used that displayed the same behavior that you have described!

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + docName);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", byteArray.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
Response.End();
```

There are two key changes that I had to make to get this to work the way I wanted *(Download the file as PDF, then open in a new tab when the user had clicked on that attachment.)* and they are both on line 3 of the code above.

**Change this**

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + docName);
```

**To this**

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + docName + ".pdf");
```

If you specify the Content-Disposition as *"Inline"* it will output the file content in your current window.

You need to change that disposition to *"attachment"* AND make sure your extension suffix is explicitly set to .pdf.

Comment: Is there any way to open the file in new tab without downloading!

Answer (score 1):

How about an alternative? Write to the browser some client side script to open a new window/tab.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptkey", "window.open('MyPDFDisplayer.ashx');");
```

Then create a new [generic handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332579/what-is-generic-handler-in-asp-net-and-its-use) MyPDFDisplayer.ashx that writes the PDF to the window.

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
context.Response.BinaryWrite(binaryData);
context.Response.End();
```

I'm a C# guy, so you'll have to translate but it should be pretty easy.