# Disallow browsing to a file directly

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

In an asp.net web forms site, I would like to disallow a user from browsing directly to files stored in a directory.  For example, i have PDFs being stored in a directory, if the user knows the path, they can simply type it in the browser address bar and pull up the PDF.

Looking for ideas on how to stop that unless they are logged in under a specific id that matches the directory name.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: maybe if there is a way where i can detect if a .pdf is opening, could call c# code to do a check.  Is that a custom handler?  I'm not familiar.

Comment: What I do is to simply _not_ store those files below the website's root, but completely outside and use an [ASHX Generic Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332579/what-is-generic-handler-in-asp-net-and-its-use) (WebForms) or a FileResult (MVC) to deliver the file to permitted users.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, go and select your Web Site, or even a specific application.

Then, nn the right side, you will find 'Directory Browsing' double-click and you will be able to disable/enable directory browsing.[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config file, add this:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="Secured">
    <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to disable directory browsing unless they are logged in under a
>   specific id

I assume this is ASP.NET Web Form.

If you use ASP.NET Membership Provider or Form Authentication, you could configure [Authorization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx) in web.config for all users and all files.

However, if users and files are constantly changing, above approach won't work.

That becomes complex. I store users and their authorized files in persistent storage like database. Then store the actual files in `App_Data` folder (or private blob storage). *IIS wont' serve the files stored inside `App_Data` folder.* Then every file request goes through Generic Handler such as `FileHandler.ashx?filename=sample.pdf`.